# Insert data into temp table using select statement?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-insert, temp-tables

I want to insert data manually into temporary table from select statement:

```
  Select into #temp from (select 1,2
    Union 
    select 2,4 
    Union 
    Select 8,12) as b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give columns a name (here I have named the columns `a` and `b`):

```
Select a, b into #temp 
from 
(
     select a = 1, b = 2 
     Union 
     select 2, 4 
     Union 
     Select 8, 12
) as t

select * from #temp

a   b
-----
1   2
2   4
8   12
```

Only the first `SELECT` clause of a `UNION` needs the explicit column names.

Comment: Do i need to pass the columns a and b in the inner query if i will pass select 1,2 instead of select a=1,b=2 ?

Comment: I'm sure not what you mean. The above answers the question you asked.

Comment: @mahadevdhyani Mitch try to explain that a columnname is necessary. So he choose a and b. Otherwise you'll receive an Error "Server: Msg 8155 
No column name was specified for column".

Comment: You can remove the subquery portion of this by moving the into to the first query. It is syntactically a little odd but perfectly valid.